# AngularJs directive to access the parent scope

Tags: angularjs

I want to show the password fields based upon the condition. Also I want to validate the password fields if it is shown. For this I have to create a directive. But the directive creates new scope for the template and does not access the parent scope to validate the password fields. How could I achieve this?

Comment: What problems are you having? Should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it through the DOM.

Send the data from the controller's scope and send that as an attribute to the directive you are creating.

```js
angular.module('App', [])
 .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = ....;
 }])
 .directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
   scope: { info = '=info' },
   template: '<div ng-repeat="i in info"> Name: {{i.name}} Password: {{i.password}}</div>',
   link: ...
  }
 });
```

```html
 
<html>
<body ng-app="App">
<div ng-controller="Controller">
 <my-directive info="data"></my-directive>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <input type='password' ng-model='user.password' class='form-control' id='password'>

Comment: This above code only I have included in the directive. I have created a new directive for the validation. For validation I have to pass "user" scope. I have tried your code. But it is throwing unexpected identifire error. I don't know what I am missing

Comment: Could you paste the complete details of the error? And hope you have filled the missing parts in my code.

Comment: app.directive("showPassword", function($compile){
    return function(scope, element){

            var template = '';
            var linkFn = $compile(template);
            var content = linkFn(scope);
            element.append(content);           
    }
  }
);

Comment: I have created the above directive. In the template I have added the html code. It is working fine now. But I want to access a parent scope in this directive. Only If that parent scope value is "true" I have to show this password filed...Else it should be empty. I cannot access the parent scope. i want my directive be like below. But how can I get the parent scope in directive?

Comment: app.directive("showPassword", function($compile){
    return function(scope, element){

            var template = '';
            var linkFn = $compile(template);
            var content = linkFn(scope);
   If(scope.showPassordField)
   {
    element.append(content);           
   }
   else
   {
    element.append('');
   }
    }
  }
);